# Is this audio read by an English native speaker or not?

Tags: pronunciation

When I listen to the following audio (uploaded in my dropbox and share it with all), the voice sounds a bit rigid. It feels like it is read by machine instead of an English native speaker. Could you please check it?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/w0vv40v4m1zbbn5/sample.mp4?dl=0

Comment: It is who that want to close my post,why ?

Comment: VTC as opinion based. My opinion is that your opinion is correct.

Comment: I don't think it's on-topic here, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: VTC because, whilst I don't feel there's anything *particularly* wrong with the question per se, it is not one that adds value to the Stack Exchange network & contains a link to a sample that it likely to vanish without trace, leaving no question at all. [vtc as 'opinion' really because there's no truly appropriate reason in the options.]

Comment: … & yes, it's a pretty bad machine voice. There are far better these days.

Comment: It's a computer voice, and a really bad one at that. It's awful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it was definitely generated by a machine.

Comment: Wondering why this is downvoted. In protest of the question? It's the right answer, and having a negative score implies it isn't.